# Reactjs Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with spotify api

Tags: reactjs, api

i can't realise what is the problem with my api fetching. Cold you please read the code and see what is going on. i initialized variable but still propery map is undefined. error is in the line 6 let trackDataPromises =playlists.map

```
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(playlistData => {
  let playlists = playlistData.items
  let trackDataPromises = playlists.map(playlist => {
    let responsePromise = fetch(playlist.tracks.href, {
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
    })
    let trackDataPromise = responsePromise
      .then(response => response.json())
    return trackDataPromise
  })
  let allTracksDataPromises = 
    Promise.all(trackDataPromises)
  let playlistsPromise = allTracksDataPromises.then(trackDatas => {
    trackDatas.forEach((trackData, i) => {
      playlists[i].trackDatas = trackData.items
        .map(item => item.track)
        .map(trackData => ({
          name: trackData.name,
          duration: trackData.duration_ms / 1000
        }))
    })
    return playlists
  })
  return playlistsPromise
})
.then(playlists => this.setState({
  playlists: playlists.map(item => {
    return {
      name: item.name,
      imageUrl: item.images[0].url, 
      songs: item.trackDatas.slice(0,3)
    }
})
}))
```

Comment: It's unknown what the response is. It's unknown which line with `map` the error refers to. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider providing enough information for other users who can't check the code against real request. A demo with dummy JSON will work.

Comment: @estus i edited my question. sorry for my oversight

Comment: Debug what `playlistData` is and why `playlistData.items` is undefined. From what I see, it's expected to be an array indeed, https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists/

Comment: @estus Thank you you were right i just now initialised  playlists array and it worked.Huge thank you for fast response

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.